# create JPA manager beans missing from eclipse 3.7.2 and JPA 2.0

Tags: eclipse

I have installed eclipse 3.7.2 and Dali JPA tools. I do not see an option to create JPA bean manager in the JPA tools menu. Do I need to install additional plugins? I am expecting to see ....

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.webtoolscore.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftjpacrtmgrbeans.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be an option which is only available in IBM Rational Application Developer (which is a commercial product).